# Python. Requests lib working via proxy(socks5 TOR) - error

Tags: python, proxy, python-requests, tor, socks

```
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 34, in <module>
    page = http.robotCheck()
  File "C:\Users\user001\Desktop\automation\Loader.py", line 21, in robotCheck
    request = requests.get('http://*redacted*.onion/login')
  File "C:\Users\user001\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 72, in get
    return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\user001\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 58, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\user001\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 512, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\user001\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 622, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\user001\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 513, in send
    raise ConnectionError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='*redacted*.onion', port=80): Max retries exceeded with url: /login (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x0348E230>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed'))
```

Here's code of my Loader class. Loader is responsible for uploading and making requests to resource over TOR. I configured proxy, but it still throws me error.
I disabled VPN, Windows firewall and everything what I could.

```
import socket
import requests

class Loader:
    url = "http://*redacted*.onion/login"
    user = "username"
    password = 'password'
    manageUrl = ''

    def __init__(self, config):
        self.config = config

        self.restartSession()

    def restartSession(self):
        self.userSession = requests.session()
        self.userSession.proxies['http'] = 'http://127.0.0.1:9050'
        self.userSession.proxies['https'] = 'https://127.0.0.1:9051'

    def robotCheck(self):
        request = requests.get('http://*redacted*.onion/login')
        print(request)
        #self.session.post(self.robotCheckUrl, data=checkResult)

    def authorization(self):
        self.session.get(self.url)
        authPage = self.session.post(self.url, data = self.getAuthData())


    def getAuthData(self):
        return {'login' : self.user, 'password' : self.password}
```

Code which call Loader class:

```
http = Loader(Config())
page = http.robotCheck()
```

Answer (score 1):

Tor is a SOCKS proxy so the proxy configuration needs to be slightly different.

Change the following lines:

```
    self.userSession.proxies['http'] = 'http://127.0.0.1:9050'
    self.userSession.proxies['https'] = 'https://127.0.0.1:9051'
```

To:

```
    self.userSession.proxies['http'] = 'socks5h://127.0.0.1:9050'
    self.userSession.proxies['https'] = 'socks5h://127.0.0.1:9050'
```

Port 9051 is the Tor Controller port.  For both HTTP and HTTPS SOCKS connections over Tor, use port 9050 (the default SOCKS port).

The `socks5h` scheme is necessary to have DNS names resolved over Tor instead of by the client.  This privatizes DNS lookups and is necessary to be able to resolve `.onion` addresses.

EDIT:  I was able to make a SOCKS request for a `.onion` address using the following example:

```
import socket
import requests

s = requests.session()
s.proxies['http'] = 'socks5h://127.0.0.1:9050'
s.proxies['https'] = 'socks5h://127.0.0.1:9050'

print(s.proxies)

r = s.get('http://***site***.onion/')
```

Make sure you have the most up-to-date requests libraries with `pip3 install -U requests[socks]'`

Comment: with the same one

Comment: actually it throws "[Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed", but host is accessable via tor, i checked it right now

Comment: @SergeyRomanov See edit.  It should work.  getaddrinfo failed means it couldn't resolve the `.onion` address which would seem that it's not using Tor to resolve the name.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap like this to get the exception only.

```
 def robotCheck(self):
    try:

        request = requests.get('http://hydraruzxpnew4af.onion/login')
        print(request)
    except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
        print('exception caught', e)
    #self.session.post(self.robotCheckUrl, data=checkResult)
```

Because of the following reasons you may get those errors:

- your server may refuse your connection (you're sending too many
  requests from same ip address in short period of time)
- Check your proxy settings

For your reference : https://github.com/requests/requests/issues/1198

Comment: Here's result: $ python main.py
exception caught HTTPConnectionPool(host='hydraruzxpnew4af.onion', port=80): Max retries exceeded with url: /login (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x02FAD1F0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed'))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 34, in <module>
    page = http.robotCheck()
  File "C:\Users\user001\Desktop\automation\Loader.py", line 28, in robotCheck
    print(request)
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'request' referenced before assignment